# Yii2 Call to a member function getRoute()

Tags: php, testes-de-unidade, phpunit, yii2

Precisei fazer uma páginação usando Yii2 no trabalho e a principio tudo ocorreu bem, testei via postman e a paginação funciona certinho.

```
 $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countConversions->count(), 'PageSize' => 50]);
    $models = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();

    $pages = [
        'totalPages'   => $pagination->getPageCount(),
        'itensPerPage' => $pagination->getPageSize(),
        'links'        => $pagination->getLinks(),
        'totalCount'   => $pagination->totalCount
    ];

    return [
        'pagination' => $pages,
        'response' => $models
    ];
```

O problema é que esta aplicação tem alguns testes unitários e praticamente todos os models são mocks.

Pois bem, após rodar criar a páginação fui rodar os testes e ele começou a falhar:

> [Error] Call to a member function getRoute() on null

Este erro ocorre porque na páginação eu estou chamando o método getLinks() e este método chama o getRoute() que pertence ao base/Controller

Já tentei mockar a Páginator usando codecept ou PHPUnit mas sempre cai no mesmo erro, é como se o retorno de método não estivesse sendo substituido. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue algumas tentativas sem sucesso:

```
        Stub::make(Pagination::class, ['getLinks' => function() { return "1";}]);


        $mockPagination = $this->createMock(Pagination::class);
        $mockPagination->expects($this->exactly(1))->method("getLinks")->willReturn("1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver e vou postar aqui caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema.

Depois de muito pesquisar vi que é bem simples de resolver, no meu metodo de teste só precisei inserir o seguinte código:

```
$mockController = $this->getMockBuilder(Controller::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->disableOriginalClone()
    ->setMethods(['getRoute'])
    ->disableArgumentCloning()
    ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
    ->getMock();

    $mockController->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('getRoute')->willReturn('1');
    Yii::$app->controller = $mockController;
```

Dessa forma eu pude fazer Mock do methodo que antes estava dando erro.